# Why is newsstand my only app in IOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-lion, ios-simulator

At one point I had to do a timemachine recovery of everything on my iMac.  Ever since then, when I open my IOS simulator, the only app it shows is Newsstand.  I have upgraded to the most recent versions of xcode (4.3.3 (4E3002)) and ios simulator (5.1 (272.21)) and still see the issue.  I have also tried removing ~/Library/Application\ Support\iPhone Simulator\ and that makes no difference.  Has anyone ever seen this problem?  What can I do to get other apps back? I really need to be able to use mobile Safari for some testing.

Comment: Did you also happen to have installed an Xcode developer preview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me before. I solved the issue by uninstalling xcode and the simulator file, which looks like the same path as yours. I then re-started my computer and re-downloaded xcode and it worked fine...

Good luck.

Comment: This worked.  Since I had already reinstalled xcode, I just had to restart my mac and it fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just logging out and then logging back in addressed the problem for me.